# Logitech USB Headset not working

Tags: 10.10, sound, headset

When I plug my USB headset in, it does not appear as hardware device within the sound preferences. However, it is present in lsusb:

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:0a14 Logitech, Inc.

It works fine in Windows and so that would suggest that it isn't a problem with the headset itself.

The native audio device in the laptop is listed as:

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cougar Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)

but I'm not sure whether this has any bearing on this situation.

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try a reboot with the headset plugged in?

Comment: Creative usb gaming headset hs-950 working flawlessly. Just had to alter 'output to usb' once in 'sound preferences', 'output' and it now plays sound through usb when I plug it in and goed back to speakers when I take it out... I also have a logitech usb headset. Now I only need to find it in all the mess I made in the other room :-D

Answer (score 2):

Where I have had audio problems and connection issues I have found the using Pulse Audio Volume Controller usually helps if you are nervous of using alsamixer which is still good

Here you can set what inputs and levels in a little clearer method

First install it in a terminal 
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
Then hit alt + f2 and type pulse and up should come the launcher for pulse audio which you can use to make sure your soundcard and inputs are all correct

I would post an image of it working but only just started on here